# Encode nested JSON array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to send nested JSON array.Which contain following format.

```
${"posts":[{
    "abc":"123",
    "xyz":"123",
    "pro":[{
        "name":"Brinjal",
        "qty":"500 gms"
    },
    {
        "name":"Brinjal",
        "qty":"500 gms"
    }] 
}]
}
```

Here is my php code:

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
if ($rows) {
     $order["posts"]   = array();
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $post = array();
        $post["order_id"] =  $row["order_id"];
        $post["order_totalamount"] = $row["order_totalamount"];
        $post["address"] = $row["address"];
        $post["pincode"] = $row["pincode"];
        $post["delivery_timeslot"] = $row["delivery_timeslot"];
        $post["order_date"] = $row["order_date"];
        $query1= "query";
        $rows1 = $stmt->fetchAll();
        if ($rows1) {
            foreach ($rows1 as $row1) {                             
                $query2= "query";
                $rows2 = $stmt->fetchAll();
                $post["product"]   = array();   
                if ($rows2) {
                    $products = array();
                    foreach ($rows2 as $row2) {
                        $products["product_name"]=$row2["product_name"];
                        $products["prod_qty"] = $row2["product_minquantity"];
                    }
                    array_push($post["product"],$products);
                    echo json_encode($products);
                }

            }
          }
        array_push($order["posts"], $post);
    }  
    echo json_encode($order);   
}
```

From above code I got result:

```
$ {"posts":
    [{
    "order_id":"18",
    "order_totalamount":"40",
    "address":"2, Chetan Society, Vadodara",
    "pincode":"390023",
    "delivery_timeslot":"Zone wise delivery",
    "order_date":"2016-03-18 17:50:53",
    "product":[{"product_name":"Brinjal","prod_qty":"500 gms"}]
    }]
}
```

But my actual product array is:

```
${"product_name":"Banana","prod_qty":"1 Kg"}{"product_name":"Brinjal","prod_qty":"500 gms"}
```

Kindly help out. I am stuck on it. tried a lot but did not get success.

Comment: What is the content of you `$order` array?

Comment: @VitorRigoni : my $order array content $post.

Comment: Can you strip all the database stuff and other things that shouldn't be necessary in the required minimal example?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt : I edited my question.

Comment: I still can't run the code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In

```
            foreach ($rows2 as $row2) {
                $products["product_name"]=$row2["product_name"];
                $products["prod_qty"] = $row2["product_minquantity"];
            }
```

You overwrite `$products["product_name"]`and `$products["prod_qty"]` with the values of the last `$row2`.

The line `{"product_name":"Banana","prod_qty":"1 Kg"}{"product_name":"Brinjal","prod_qty":"500 gms"}` actually consists of two echo's:

1. `{"product_name":"Banana","prod_qty":"1 Kg"}`
2. `{"product_name":"Brinjal","prod_qty":"500 gms"}`

But you don't see the difference. I suggest echoing a string in-between them or use something like `var_dump()` to see how many values you're echoing.

You should do something like:

```
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($rows2); $i++) {
            $products[$i]["product_name"]=$rows2[$i]["product_name"];
            $products[$i]["prod_qty"] = $rows2[$i]["product_minquantity"];
        }
```

This will result in: `[{"product_name":"Banana","prod_qty":"1 Kg"},{"product_name":"Brinjal","prod_qty":"500 gms"}]`

FYI `$array[] =` has the same rsults as `array_push()`, but had less overhead of calling `array_push()`.

---

**EDIT:**
Below a complete example since it doesn't seem to workout for you:

```
//Demo $order
$order = array (
    'posts' => 
    array (
        0 => 
        array (
            'order_id' => '18',
            'order_totalamount' => '40',
            'address' => '2, Chetan Society, Vadodara',
            'pincode' => '390023',
            'delivery_timeslot' => 'Zone wise delivery',
            'order_date' => '2016-03-18 17:50:53',
        ),
    ),
);

//Demo $rows2
$rows2 = array(
    array(
        'product_name' => 'banana', 
        'product_minquantity' => '1 Kg'
    ),
    array(
        'product_name' => 'Brinjal', 
        'product_minquantity' => '500 gms'
    )
);

$post['product'] = array();   
if ($rows2) {
    $products = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($rows2); $i++) {
        $products[$i]['product_name'] = $rows2[$i]['product_name'];
        $products[$i]['prod_qty']     = $rows2[$i]['product_minquantity'];
    }
    $post['product'] = $products;
    echo json_encode($products); //[{"product_name":"banana","prod_qty":"1 Kg"},{"product_name":"Brinjal","prod_qty":"500 gms"}]
}
//$order['posts'][] = $post;
$order['posts'][0] = $order['posts'][0] + $post;
//In this example I only have 1 item in $order['posts'] so I know to add to key 0.
//In your case you need to know which key of $rows1 you need to do the adding.
//Change the foreach loop of $rows to a for loop as well so you can define your own keynames ($i).
echo '<br>==================================================================<br>';
echo json_encode($order);
/*
    {
    "posts":[
      {
         "order_id":"18",
         "order_totalamount":"40",
         "address":"2, Chetan Society, Vadodara",
         "pincode":"390023",
         "delivery_timeslot":"Zone wise delivery",
         "order_date":"2016-03-18 17:50:53",
         "product":[
            {
               "product_name":"banana",
               "prod_qty":"1 Kg"
            },
            {
               "product_name":"Brinjal",
               "prod_qty":"500 gms"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
*/
```

Comment: if i do the same. i got product array null.

Comment: Impossible since you declare `$products` as an array. It could be an empty array if `$rows2` is empty also. Please var_dump `$rows2` before the for loop and `$products` at the end, but within the for loop.

Comment: I did had a typo in my for loop `$row2` must be `$rows2` ofcourse as I already corrected.

Comment: Does the downvoter care to explain his vote? I made effort to help make his code work. The example in my answer works and produces exactly the output where asked for. Even if OP can't copy/paste my code in his script to make it work, it must certainly help to push OP in the right direction. Your downvote cost me rep point while putting effort into the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help. but it didn't work out for me. actual I want array like this: `{
   "posts":[
      {
         "order_id":"18",
         "order_totalamount":"40",
         "address":"2, Chetan Society, Vadodara",
         "pincode":"390023",
         "delivery_timeslot":"Zone wise delivery",
         "order_date":"2016-03-18 17:50:53",
         "product":[
            {
               "product_name":"banana",
               "prod_qty":"1 Kg"
            },
            {
               "product_name":"Brinjal",
               "prod_qty":"500 gms"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}`

Comment: I've updated my example for getting desired output, but read the comments in my code. The foreach loop of `$rows1` needs to be changed to a for loop as well. Just as I did for `$rows2`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. but as per your suggestions if I update my code, then I get product array is: `[{"product_name":"Banana","prod_qty":"1 Kg"}][{"product_name":"Brinjal","prod_qty":"500 gms"}]`.

Comment: Hy, Thanks a lot for your great support. it helps me a lot. you made my day. It's now work perfectly with some modification in your given code. once again thank you so much.

Comment: Glad I was able to help you out. Good luck with your future coding.